# Access data points scikit KNNR

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, nearest-neighbor

### Question

After fitting the data with neigh.fit() I would like to access these data-points, how do I do this?

### Details

```
>>> samples = [[0., 0., 0.], [0., .5, 0.], [1., 1., .5]]
>>> samplesy = [80, 60, 40]
>>> from sklearn import neighbors
>>> neigh = neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=1)
>>> neigh.fit(samples, samplesy) 
>>> print(neigh.kneighbors([1., 1., 1.])) 
(array([[ 0.5]]), array([[2]]))
```

So from this I learned that the closest data-point is 'samples[2]'.
However in the case I don't have access anymore to the variable 'samples', is there a way to access the data-point in 'neigh'? Maybe something like 'neigh[2]'? Because the data-points have to be saved somewhere in the model of 'neigh' right?

### Why

I would like to access the 5 closest neighbors data-points and calculate a cluster-center of these  data-points. Then I want to calculate the distance of this cluster-center to the new data point to get an idea of how far this new data-point is from the original data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data used to fit the model are stored in `neigh._fit_X`:

```
>>> neigh._fit_X
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0.5,  0. ],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  0.5]])
```

**However:** The leading underscore of the variable name should be a signal to you that this is supposed to be somewhat of a *private* attribute. You shouldn't expect for this data to behave in any particular way, or even to exist in future versions of the library. Use it at your own risk.

A better way might be to just keep track of the input data on your own.